# selecting files and saving it to the defined location using folder browse dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

I had made this code for user to select a folder so that my two files will be copied to that. The code is this:

```
string sourcePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\akib\";
string fileName1 = @"untitled.jpg";
string fileName2 = @"Copyuntitled.jpg";
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var destinationFolderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    if (Directory.Exists(destinationFolderName))
    {
        File.Copy(sourcePath + "/" + fileName1, destinationFolderName
                  + "/" + fileName1);
        File.Copy(sourcePath + "/" + fileName2, destinationFolderName 
                  + "/" + fileName2);
    }
}
```

But now I want to to reverse of it. That is if user have two files in some location I want to copy that to the `c:\programfiles\myfolder`. So `FolderBrowseDialog` can be used in such case? If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you would want to use the OpenFileDialog class with the Multiselect property set to true:

```
string destination = @"c:\programfiles\myfolder";
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Multiselect = true;
if (DialogResult.OK == ofd.ShowDialog()) {
    foreach (string file in ofd.FileNames)  {
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(file)));
    }
}
```

Comment: and sir how i cave written this File.Copy(sourcePath + "/" + fileName2, destinationFolderName + "/" + fileName2); can be written instead of this File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(file))); your is quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

FolderBrowseDialog can be used in exactly the same manner for getting a folder for reading or writing files.